# jquery ajax request cross domain with jsonp does not work in IE6

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, jsonp, internet-explorer-6

I make a jquery plugin look like:

```
(function($){
$.fn.plugin_name = function(){
    var methods = {
        getSomeThing: function(callback){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                url: 'http://thirdparty.com/get',       
                success: function(response){
                    callback(response);
                }
            });
        },
        getDetail: function(callback){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                url: 'http://thirdparty.com/getdetail',
                data:{id:1},
                success: function(response){
                    //this code block has never executed in IE6
                },
                error: function(request, status, error){
                    alert(request.statusText); // i get "success" in IE6
                    alert(status); // i get "parseerror" in IE6
                    alert(error.error); // i get [object Error] in IE6
                }
            });
        }
    };

    return this.each(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        methods.getSomeThing(function(response){ // work OK
            //process response
            self.html(response.html); // work OK

            self.append('<a href="javascript:;" id="linkDetail">View Detail</a>');

            self.on('click','#linkDetail',function(){
                //i make an ajax request here
                methods.getDetail(function(response){
                    //failed!!
                });
            });

        });
    });
}
```

})(jQuery);

I used jsonp to making requests across domains.

It works fine on Firefox, Chrome, IE7,8 but no luck on IE6.

There is something wrong at method **getDetail**, when i click **View Detail** link, i got errors.

I try to debug it with Fiddler, then i don't see any request when i click **View Detail**, but i still got the errors ?!

I can not figure this problem, someone help me, please! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem! I just want to share with you this tip.

Seem there is something wrong when event click was fired on an anchor like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="linkDetail">View Detail</a>
```

I use event.preventDefault() in this case, so the default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
self.on('click','#linkDetail',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
            //i make an ajax request here
            methods.getDetail(function(response){
                //failed!!
            });
        });
```

Then everything work fine in IE6!